# Changes after convert to MotionLayout not recorded in git

Tags: git, android-studio, android-motionlayout, github-desktop

In a new fragment with a `ConstraintLayout` I convert it to `MotionLayout` by selecting the menu option "Convert to MotionLayout"

The conversion completes successfully and the xml file with the `MotionScene` is created

The problem is that none of these changes is recorded in git! I'm using GitHub Desktop and  after the conversion, there are no changes that I can commit. None of the changes to the fragment are recorded and the xml file with the `MotionScene` doesn't appear as created in git.

Also, after making other changes to that particular fragment (for example delete everything from the layout) don't appear to GitHub Desktop anymore. It is as if changes to the fragment are ignored.

Changes to other source files are recorded as usual to GitHub Desktop

By the way, there are no changes to `.gitignore` file (`.gitignore` doesn't appear as having changes in GitHub Desktop)

Anyone knows why this thing is happening and how I can correct it?

Comment: Are the files you're changing listed in `.gitignore`? And the files you're changing already tracked in your Git repo, or newly created by these operations?

Comment: If you run `git status --ignored=matching` on the command prompt, does it say anything about that file? Is the file actually inside the Git sandbox you're working in, or does it get created/modified elsewhere on your file system?

Comment: @joanis  Thanks a lot. Seems that in previous commit, there was the entry `*.xml` in `.gitignoree` and the particular file that I was working on stopped being tracked (not only that file, but it just happened to work only on that particular one)